# NSURLRequest timeout interval default time

Tags: ios, request, request-timed-out

Can you share your answer to me for

1. `NSURLRequest` default `timeoutInterval` time
2. `NSMutableURLRequest` default `timeoutInterval` time

Comment: The default time is 240 seconds.

Comment: @Guy Kogus for NSMutableURLRequest post method default time is 240 sec
what about NSURLRequest default timeoutInterval time ?

Comment: Sorry, it's 60 seconds. You can test it easily by just creating a simple `NSURLRequest` object and logging the timeout interval.

Answer (score 20):

For both NSURLRequest & NSMutableURLRequest default timeoutInterval time is 60 secs

Answer (score 16):

> The default cache policy is `NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy` and the default timeout interval is 60 seconds.

[NSURLRequest Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURLRequest/requestWithURL:)

Comment: In document (provided in the link) the sentence is not available. @tonyspiff

Comment: @PremalKhetani The information about the default cache policy and timeout interval can be found in the documentation for the `requestWithURL:` method, which is listed at the link posted in the answer.

Answer (score 8):

Maybe you can do a small test then you would konw:[image]

Answer (score 2):

FYI - the interval changed with iOS 6.0 from 240 to 60.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmutableurlrequest/1414063-timeoutinterval?language=objc

Answer (score 1):

For reference, the default timeout interval is defined within the header file for `NSURLRequest`, by the side of `+requestWithURL:`

[image: NSURLRequest timeoutInterval]

It explicitly says it's **60 seconds**.